# Android splash screen doesn't show

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I'm trying to show splash screen before my main activity's layout shows.
I do it like this (PuzzleActivity is my main activity):

```
public class PuzzleActivity extends Activity{
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ...
    ... (Do some background work)
    ...
    Thread.sleep(20000); // Sleep for 20 seconds
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

I would expect my splash screen to show for at least 20 seconds.

Nevertheless, it doesn't show at all. Instead I see a black screen for 20 secs, and then my main activity screen...

When I tried to remove the last setContentView(), I saw my splash screen.

Can someone tell my why I don't see my splash screen when using the code above?

Comment: Thread.sleep() is the problem. Use Handler with postDelayed(new Runnable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the screen is empty until the Activity's onCreate() method is over.
Therefore, the only thing I had to do is move the processing work to be executed out of the onCreate() method (with a handler).
Then, I could easily switch the contentview.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep(time)` causes the thread which sent this message to sleep for the given interval of time.

Calling `Thread.sleep(20000);` from the UI thread will make it sleep for 20 seconds leaving your activity unresponsive which generally is a bad idea.

I personally build a dedicated launcher activity for splash screens and once the desired amount of time has passed I navigate to the main activity, in your case it would be something like as follows:

```
   public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

        // Splash screen time in milliseconds
        private static final long LOADING_TIME = 2000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            Thread timer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        sleep(LOADING_TIME);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, PuzzleActivity.class);
                        startActivity(openMainActivity );
                        SplashActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                }
            };

            timer.start();          
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first `setContentView` and then run your `Thread` like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(1*1000);

                Intent i=new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //Remove activity
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    // start thread
    background.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android, splash screens should be avoided as much as possible. So not showing it will both solve your problem and make your app follow the guidelines. Unless you have some heavy loading going on.

> If your application has a time-consuming initial setup phase, consider showing a splash screen or rendering the main view as quickly as possible, indicate that loading is in progress and fill the information asynchronously. In either case, you should indicate somehow that progress is being made, lest the user perceive that the application is frozen. ([source](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html))

Some links worth reading too (either for you or your client):

- http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html
- http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

(yes, in the end, the client makes the decision, but a little education is never useless)

Answer (score 0):

What i do is this:

Manifest:

> ```
> <activity
>         android:name="com.antonis.android.eventz.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="splashImage" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.antonis.android.eventz.SplashActivity"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

and then this in my splash class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("splashImage"));
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}
```